# How to use LD_PRELOAD without killing the process

Tags: c, linux, hook, ptrace, ld-preload

I have running process that I want to hook on specific function.

The main idea was killing the process and run it again with LD_PRELOAD and that work.

The problem is that I don't want to kill the process,or using `ptrace` (because I don't want to set the process under debugging state all the time)

Is there any way to use LD_PRELOAD on running process?

I assume the I need to load the so into the process memory and change the import table.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible in general if you can't use `ptrace`. The problem is that unlike `PTRACE_POKETEXT`, `process_vm_writev` can't write to read-only pages. On modern systems with RELRO and such, anything that you could overwrite to accomplish your goal will be read-only after the process starts.